# All branches are missing after backing up git repository

Tags: git

I migrated my workstation and backed up all my files by copying ~/Users/me

However, looking into my git repositories, all my branches are now gone (git branch -a)! There is only one master.

Does anyone know why none of my branches are there anymore? I thought they are coupled with the repository...

```
$ ls -l .git/refs/heads/
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 noob  noob  41 Oct 10 16:34 master
```

Comment: Git branches are stored in files, just like any other file (they're small files, since they are just a pointer to a commit). Copying everything should copy all your branches, too. Unfortunately there isn't enough information provided to determine why you are not seeing what you expect to see.

Comment: What kind of information could help?

Comment: At the very least, the output of `ls -l .git/refs/heads` on the old and new repositories would be enlightening.

Comment: Did you also copy the hidden .git folder that lives in the root of your for repository?

Comment: It might help to know how you copied your User directory.

Comment: There's also `.git/packed-refs` which is where refs get moved-to for saving some space, but they would still show up in the output of `git branch`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out IT did not backup any of my dotfiles when performing the migration... I deserve all the downvotes -.-

Comment: Sounds like it's *IT* that deserves the downvotes.  You've had an encounter with [Mordac the Preventer](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Mordac%20The%20Preventer)!